# Network adapter IPv4 DNS settings keep returning to 8.8.8.8

Tags: windows, networking, dns

At some point in the past, I have set my WiFi adapter settings to use Google's DNS servers `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. This causes that I cannot connect to some WiFis because of how their "login screens" are implemented (malls, cafes etc.). It needs to be "Obtain DNS automatically" which I have now manually set countless of times.

However, for some reason, the DNS settings seem to randomly return back to Google DNS values. It's certainly not me who's doing that, and it doesn't happen too frequently – like only every couple of days. What could it be? How could I track it down? Would there be something in the event log or something?

Comment: When the change to google DNS happens, does this mean that the 'automatic` setting disabled itself, or is it still on and the DNS server just happens to be a Google one? Does it happen on specific places?

Comment: In the IPv4 properties dialog, in the bottom part, "Use the following DNS server addresses" is selected.